# How can I find out what's on a certain block in an HFS+ formatted drive?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery, bad-sectors, hfs

I've a hard disk that has damaged blocks. I'm now copying it using ddrescue to an external drive.

I've a file with the list of the damaged blocks, how can I find out which files are located in the damaged blocks?

Comment: Ooh, good question.  I've been wondering the same thing.